# How to modify data in recyclerview by changing filter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

what I want to do is update the recyclerview information as I enter some text to filter information. I use "notifydatasetchange" but it does not show anything. The filtered information is ok.

This is my global list

```
var productList: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf()
```

this is the adapter function which displays the first time ok

```
private fun buildProductAdapter(filter: String) {
        productList = Product().getProductsByFilter(filter)
        productListAdapter = ProductListAdapter(applicationContext, productList, cashOrCredit)
        rcvProducts.adapter = productListAdapter
    }
```

then, when the text has changed

```
private fun notifyProductListFilterChanged() {
    val filter: String = if (edtSearchProduct.text.toString() != "") edtSearchProduct.text.toString() else ""

    productList.clear()
    productList = Product().getProductsByFilter(filter)
    productListAdapter!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

}
```

But when I get to that function, it just does not display anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you change the reference of your variable to a new list

`productList = Product().getProductsByFilter(filter)`

while the adapter still holds the reference to the old one.

Instead, add your new items to the same list:

`productList.addAll(Product().getProductsByFilter(filter))`

Comment: that did it. Thank you

Comment: Np, happy coding!

Comment: hey... I am trying to modify one object of the list and after that, do another filter, but keeping the modified value, but with the clear() before doing the notifyDataSetChanged() the list is reseted... any help on how to approach this? thanks in advanced